# TP-LINK TL-WN721N USB Wi-Fi adapter not detected in VMWare Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, vmware, kali-linux

Since the [a TP-LINK TL-WN721N](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WN721N) USB Wi-Fi adapter is one of the few that works with Kali normally. I am having trouble having it detected as a Wireless Adapter in a Virtual Machine.

I installed Kali and Tools etc on VMWare. Updated the OS and everything. I have one default ethernet installed. I connected the USB adapter and switched it to the guest OS but nothing happens. The adapter shows up `lsusb` as

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Its the 5th entry down as you see. But `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` yield no results.

Answer (score 0):

It’s odd, my version of Kali (running via VirtualBox) has all it needs to deal with this dongle.

So, step by step:

1. Confirm that you have the driver for the dongle:

```
# modinfo ath9k_htc | grep 0CF3 | grep 9271
 alias:          usb:v0CF3p9271d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

If `modinfo` generates no reply, then you have no driver. The driver comes with your linux-image, I guess in this case you will have to re-install it.

2. Confirm you have the relevant firmware,`/lib/firmware/htc_9271.fw`. If not, install the `firmware-atheros` package.
3. If you have everything, then

```
modprobe ath9k_htc
```

should give you a working USB. If not, look carefully at the error messages, especially with `dmesg`.

Comment: @JakeGould Nope, VirtualBox. However the OP states that the dongle is recognized by lsusb,but no interface is created (no iwconfig, no ifconfig output). Hence there is clearly no driver present, nothing else comes in between. Unless, of course, `lsusb` was issued on the host, instead of the VM...